# How can I find certain letters in a string?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I'm looking for a way to find the capital letters in a string. The string is stored inside a variable. I want those capital letters in a new string.

Comment: Give some examples of what you have and what you want to extract.

Comment: If you want an answer for what you're looking for, first answer to the queries in the comments and add to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since, you have not specified anything yet, here's my solution to what I think you are asking for.

```py
import re

text = 'ABGHTD abdfc 5373 ddgh'
[x for x in re.findall('[a-zA-Z]*', text) if x.strip()!=""]
```

**Output**:

```
['ABGHTD', 'abdfc', 'ddgh']
```

### Extracting All the Capital Letters as a Single String

```py
import re 

text = 'ABGHTD abDFc 5373 ddXgh'
segments = [x for x in re.findall('[A-Z+]*', text) if x.strip()!=""]
segments_as_string = ''.join(segments)

print(segments)
print(segments_as_string)
```

**Output**:

```
['ABGHTD', 'DF', 'X']
ABGHTDDFX
```

Comment: But what do you think I'm asking for? I'm not looking for specific letters, but can I isolate capital letters in one string to make a new string?

Comment: We really cannot help you any more, without you giving us specific example of what you have and what you want. Please update your question first.

Comment: @Anonymous Thank you for `voting up`. Please consider choosing one of the answers as the **`accepted`** answer.

Answer (score 0):

use regex with or condition

```py
import re

text = 'This is sTring TO sEARch'

re.findall(r"^.|[A-Z]| .", text)
```

**Result**

```
['T', ' i', ' s', 'T', ' T', 'O', ' s', 'E', 'A', 'R']
```

Answer (score 0):

While I feed regex is the best option here. I wanted to show there are a few ways to skin a cat.

**Using comparisons and loops, we can see if its an uppercase character**

```
>>> from string import ascii_uppercase     
>>>
>>> ascii_uppercase
'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'   
>>>
>>> test_string = "Go REAd The banJO Book"
>>> search_uppercase = lambda haystack: [x for x in haystack if x in ascii_uppercase]  
>>> search_uppercase(test_string)
['G', 'R', 'E', 'A', 'T', 'J', 'O', 'B']
>>>
>>> ''.join(search_uppercase(test_string))
 'GREATJOB'
```

**Using regex**

```
>>> import re
>>> test_string
'Go REAd The banJO Book'
>>>
>>> re.findall(r'[A-Z]', test_string)
['G', 'R', 'E', 'A', 'T', 'J', 'O', 'B']
>>>
>>> re.findall(r'[A-Z ]', test_string)
['G', ' ', 'R', 'E', 'A', ' ', 'T', ' ', 'J', 'O', ' ', 'B']
>>>
>>> findings = re.findall(r'[A-Z]', test_string)
>>> ''.join(findings)
'GREATJOB'
```

**Edit:** Just noticed the " or the letters at the beginning and after spaces."

```
>>> test_string                                                                                                         
'Go REAd The banJO Book'
>>> re.findall(r'(\S \S)', test_string)                                                                                 
['o R', 'd T', 'e b', 'O B']
```

Unfortunately, this method isn't so great and checking for actual words.

```
>>> test_string = "Go REAd The banJO Book!"
>>> re.findall(r'(\S \S)', test_string)
['o R', 'd T', 'e b', 'O B'] # If only we could get that k at the end and the G at the beginning!
>>> re.findall(r'(\w+\b)', test_string)
['Go', 'REAd', 'The', 'banJO', 'Book']
>>> finder_keepers = re.findall(r'(\w+\b)', test_string)
>>> [w[0]+' '+w[-1] for w in finder_keepers]
['G o', 'R d', 'T e', 'b O', 'B k']
```